# Why my Save button and Cancel Button doesn't show after I clicked the New Product button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

I'm a beginner in javascript.

When I clicked the New Product button new Row will be added in the table(that worked out). But, Save button and Cancel button supposedly will show up(and it didn't work) and the New Product button will be hidden(still didn't work).

Here's a part of my HTML where I declared my buttons and the table.

```
<table id="dataTable" class="poductTable" border="1" cellspacing="2" width="75%" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>Unit</td>
            <td>Qty</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td><input type="text"></td>
            <td><input type="text"></td>
            <td><input type="text"></td>
            <td><input type="text"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>


    <table align="center" id="productActions">
        <tr>
            <td><button type="button" onclick="saveProd()" id="saveProd" style="display:none;">Save</button></td>
            <td><button type="button" onclick="cancelProd()" id="cancelProd" style="display:none;">Cancel</button></td>
            <td><button type="button" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" id="newProd">New Product</button></td>
            <td><button type="button" onclick="editProduct()" id="editProd">Edit Product</button></td>
            <td><button type="button" onclick="delProduct()" id="delProd">Delete Product</button></td>

        </tr>
    </table>
```

Here is the part of my script.

```
function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    cell1.innerHTML = rowCount + 0;

    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var element1 = document.createElement("input");
    element1.type = "text";
    element1.name = "newProdName[]";
    cell2.appendChild(element1);

    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var element2 = document.createElement("input");
    element2.type = "text";
    element2.name = "newProdDesc[]";
    cell3.appendChild(element2);

    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var element3 = document.createElement("input");
    element3.type = "text";
    element3.name = "newProdUnit[]";
    cell4.appendChild(element3);

    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
    var element4 = document.createElement("input");
    element4.type = "text";
    element4.name = "newProdQty[]";
    cell5.appendChild(element4);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#newProd').click(function () {
            $(this).hide();
            $('#saveProd').show();
            $('#cancelProd').show();
        });
});
```

Thank you for helping in advance.

Comment: your code is working as expected http://jsfiddle.net/zb6b2dcw/

Comment: @v31 but the save and cancel buttons doesn't show up.

Comment: When you click on the New product button they are showing in the fiddle that I shared. The fiddle has your code only

Comment: You have to add the `click` code to the Save and Cancel buttons in order to show New Product again.

Comment: I've already added the **click** code but still it doesn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had the same issue before

Not sure if its the correct fix, but i used JavaScript to hide the elements

HTML:

```
<td><button type="button" onclick="saveProd()" id="saveProd">Save</button></td>
<td><button type="button" onclick="cancelProd()" id="cancelProd">Cancel</button></td>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#saveProd').hide();
        $('#cancelProd').hide();

        $('#newProd').click(function () {
            $(this).hide();
            $('#saveProd').show();
            $('#cancelProd').show();
        });
});
```

Comment: Still, it doesn't worked. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: @RMiram Is there any errors in your browser console?